# Firestarter exits after closing

Tags: 12.04, firewall, firestarter

I'm using Firestarter on **Ubuntu 12.04**.

I **configured** Firestarter **to run even after closing** in the preferences menu.

But still it exits after closing.

**It doesn't minimize to system tray**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things, and a recommendation.

First, **Firestarter isnt the firewall itself**.  It is a graphical front-end to the `iptables` firewall that comes with ubuntu by default.  `iptables` will always run.  However, with Firestarter, when it closes, it clears out the `iptables` rules, which is why Firestarter needs to remain open for the firewall to work.

Secondly, **this might be a bug in Firestarter itself**, and you should [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firestarter/+filebug) as such.

Thirdly, **Firestarter is not recommended for use anymore**, due to it not having been updated in a while, since support for it has been dropped from Ubuntu developers.  Therefore, it is more strongly recommended to use `ufw` or `gufw` (gui frontend for ufw) in place of Firestarter, as that is updated actively, and is actively developed.  Like Firestarter, they work with the `iptables` backend.  They, however, leave the rules in place upon exit, so the firewall rules will still run, unlike with Firestarter.

Comment: thank you. This gufw also closes after exiting. I can't seem to find in preferences to configure to run even after closing.

Comment: It will always run. The front ends configure the backend called `iptables`, which is *always running*. You are confusing the front-end configuration utilities with the actual firewall program. Which is what I said in the first point i made in my answer. Using them to configure, and then closing the firewall configuration program, will not disable the firewall, since the backend that they configure, `iptables`, is *always running*.  (Firestarter's the exception, it actually opens up the firewall on its own shutdown, which is not good form)